# How do you generate a CRL certificate file in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, certificate, x509

Using `makecert.exe` I can take a pvk file and generate a CRL using the following command:

> makecert.exe -crl -n "CN=Foobar" -r -sv "Foobar.pvk" "Foobar.crl"

What is the equivalent Powershell command?

The following code uses Powershell to generate the PVK and CER files, but I can't figure out how to generate the CRL

```
$rootcert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "CN=Foobar" -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My 
$PFXPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "my password" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $('cert:\LocalMachine\My\' + $rootcert.Thumbprint) -Password $PFXPass -FilePath "Foobar.pvk"
Export-Certificate -Cert $('cert:\LocalMachine\My\' + $rootcert.Thumbprint) -FilePath "Foobar.cer"
```

Comment: I don't think there are any cmdlets for generating or signing CRLs, my recommendation would be to simply continue using `makecert.exe` or try to work out the underlying API and invoke that via PowerShell

Comment: Why do you need a different command? `makecert.exe` works in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Three things to consider:

1. `makecert.exe` tool is deprecated and no longer recommended for use: [MakeCert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. CRL generation for self-signed certificates is useless and makes no sense. Revocation for self-signed certificates is undefined, because it leads to an egg and chicken problem. And they use explicit trust.
3. Manual CRL generation is an unmaintainable solution. You should use CA software to run your own CA and automate CA-specific routines.